# which SharePoint online list i need to use to migrate an on-premsies sharepoint 2010 "Project Tasks" list

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010, migration, tasks

I am working on a sharepoint on-premises 2010 farm, where we are planning to migrate it to sharepoint online. now we are planning to use a third party tool (named avepoint) to do the migration, but i have noted one thing is that inside the SP on-prem 2010 there are many lists of type "Project Tasks", as follow:-

[image]

now i am planning to check with the vendor of the migration tool on how those lists will be migrated as in sharepoint online we do not have any list type named "Project Tasks"..

so can anyone advice on this please? generally speaking what is the sharepoint online list template which replace the "Project Tasks" list found in SP 2010?

Comment: There is "Tasks" list template in classic experience in SharePoint online.

Comment: @GaneshSanap thanks for the info, but in SP 2010 we got 2 list templates "Tasks" and "Project Tasks" ,, so you mean in SP online the 2 on-premises list templates can be replaced by the "Tasks"? i am not sure if the 3rd party tool we are using for the migration will automatically migrate the on-premises "Project Tasks" as online "Tasks"? but if this is not the case, then can i manually migrate the on-premises "Project Tasks" as online "Tasks"?

Answer (score 1):

As Ganesh suggested, Task list in SP Online can be used as replacement for Project tasks in SP 2010.

Here is link to official documentation on connecting task list to project.

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/create-and-manage-a-project-task-list-466ad207-46fd-4c77-9af1-41bc23cec21a#ID0EAACAAA=Online,_2016,_2013

Comment: ok thanks for the info, now since we are planning to use a third party migration tool, so i am not sure if it will automatically migrate any on-premises "Project Tasks" list as online "Tasks" list, i will check with the vendor.. but  my main concern now, if the 3rd party migration tool will not  migrate any on-premises "Project Tasks" list as online "Tasks" list, then can i manually convert the on-premises "Project Tasks" lists to online "Tasks" lists?

Comment: Just FYI the Task list will stick out like a word thumb as it will always be in classic mode. Nothing wrong with that, just plan for it

Comment: @KasperBoLarsen Ok fine,since this is the only option then we have to live with it, or till MS provide a modern UI for the Tasks list. but my main concern on how i can manually convert the on-premises Project Tasks list into an online Tasks list?

Comment: I think 3rd party tool will migrate...that’s what they do...see in the end project list is also a normal list only with different column types